# How to backup SQL Server database (mdf) programmatically to later import it rowwise?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

My aim is to backup a database (.mdf) as one file with my web application project written in C#.
The backup should later on be loaded on a "restore"-page, where the data in the backed-up tables could be appended to the original database row by row.
What would be a good practice to implement this?
I thought of just copying the mdf file, but then I read about attaching and detaching of the database. Furthermore I don't know what to do with the _log.ldf file.

I'm looking forward to your hints. Thank you in advance for your help!

EDIT: I can only use the free SQL Server Express for this, because I want to distribute my program to other people.

Comment: Do you have written the code for taking backup in C#?

Comment: I haven't written any code for backup, but the code behind of the asp.net/ web application project is written in C#.

Comment: Perhaps I do not understand, but if you backup the database and append the data again to the original database you get duplicate rows....

Comment: By "rowwise" do you really *need* it to be rowwise, or are you just avoiding answers that say "copy and restore the DB files"?

Comment: @ Pleun: That is why I want to do the restore row by row. I mean that a user sees the entries of the backup-database and can select a whole row, if he wants it appended to the original-database.

Comment: @ Merlyn Morgan-Graham: See my comment above. I want to do it rowwise to avoid unwanted duplicated database entries.

Comment: But if it coming from a backup, it is already there... Anyway, I wrote an anwer with a slightly different approach that may suit you

Comment: I agree with Pleun.  While a number of backup solutions have been presented, there is no mechanism presented for doing the restore row by row using a backup file.  An app-specific file of some sort would be ideal for what K B is trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably, you refer to the [Backup and Restore using C# for Sql Server](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1849/backup-and-restore-sql-server-databases-programmatically-with-smo/) to get a complete idea about writting a code in C#, which has helped me a lot when I was using it.

By the use of [Backup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.backup.aspx) class in C#, you can get all the facilities to backup as well as restore.

Comment: So I need MSSQL Server installed to use this library? Would MSSQL Server Express suffice?

Comment: No, need of installing MSSQL Server. You can work with .net default server explorer OLEDB connection.

Comment: Can you provide a solution to process the backup file and evaluate the restore on a row-by-row basis?

Comment: @skk: My program should be distributed to people with the free MSSQL Express. If I use an OLEDB connection I can not use the power auf the Backup class?

Answer (score 1):

If you are only interested in appending the data rowwise afterwards, perhaps it is easier to export each table to CSV and import it afterwards (so you have rowwwise control in C#).

If you insist ine one file, just add all the CSV's to a zip.

You can use the FileHelpers library for this (http://www.filehelpers.com/) and you will have it up&running in no time.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is a `Backup` class in the SQL Server Management Objects library.

You might want to check that out first, as it doesn't look overly complicated:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.backup.aspx

It would require you to have two or three libraries installed on the server you run it on, though they are fairly small - not Windows SDK sized...

Answer (score 0):

pls go through this link on how to [backup data and restore](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SQL_Server_2005_Database.aspx) using c# and sql server .In addition to you have to add these names spaces

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
```